# Can [single] Linear Regression be inferred from Multiple Regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

A student posed a question: she has observations from two, independent groups for variables `Y` and `X`. She drops them on a `Y~X` plot, asks the console to make separate lines for both groups (call this variable `G`), and asks "how do I test if the two lines are significantly different?"

I suggest the following: Make linear regression models `Y~X` for both groups, then use something like ANCOVA.

My P.I. buds in and suggests the following: Create a single multiple regression model of the form `Y~X*G` which results in $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1X + \beta_2G + \beta_3XG$. From this, he says without really explaining, you can derive two separate (presumably independent) regression lines which you can plot, and then perform tests on.

My question is: am I going insane or is he completely wrong? Can singular regression really be inferred from multiple regression like that? And what should I recommend to the student?

Comment: Is variable $G$ supposed to denote group membership?

Comment: Yes, receives two values.